# Ember observe nested model property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In EmberJS, if I want to observe a property "selectedValue" which is inside a nested model, how can I do that ?

The below does not seem to be working;

```
modelChanged: function() {  

}.observes('myModel.@each.@each.selectedValue'),
```

Also the below does not work

```
modelChanged: function() {  

}.observes('myModel'),
```

This is how myModel looks like

```
[
    [{
        "prop1": "abc_1",
        "selectedValue": "abc_1"
    }, {
        "prop1": "xyz_1",
        "selectedValue": "xyz_1"
    }],
    [{
        "prop1": "abc_2",
        "selectedValue": "abc_2"
    }, {
        "prop1": "xyz_2",
        "selectedValue": "xyz_2"
    }],
    [{
        "prop1": "abc_3",
        "selectedValue": "abc_3"
    }, {
        "prop1": "xyz_1",
        "selectedValue": "xyz_1"
    }]
]
```

Update based on

Seems to be working...Just a couple of questions;

> 1. In above code, "observedObjects" just adds for the first outer array and tracks property within this arr[0]. I have multiple outer
>      array elements
>
>    2. How can I modify the above to track for multiple properties ? i.e.
>         In some cases, it would be "selectedValue" OR it can be
>         "preSelectedValue" in other cases . What property it is would depend
>         upon that object itself. But I need to track change of either
>         selectedValue/preSelectedValue
>    3. Also in observerMethod, can I get
>         a context and check what the new selectedValue/preSelectedValue is?

Answer (score 1):

What is the structure of your nested model? If myModel is an array of elements with selectedValue, you can use `myModel.@each.selectedValue`. If you need multiple levels of nesting, that's not supported out of the box.

From the [documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/):

> Note that @each only works one level deep. You cannot use nested forms like todos.@each.owner.name or todos.@each.owner.@each.name.

There are workarounds that depend on your model structure, and if you reply or update the question with your structure I'll update my answer to cover an appropriate solution.

**Update:** Depending on how `myModel` is set/updated, you may need to adjust when `observeMyModelChildren` is called and how it creates observers.

```
// observerMethod is called when myModel.@each.@each.selectedValue changes
observerMethod: function () {
  // handle change
},

// observedObjects tracks child observers so they can be removed
observedObjects: [],

// observeMyModelChildren listens for changes to myModel, removes 
// old observers, and adds new ones 
observeMyModelChildren: function () {
  const key = '@each.selectedValue';

  this.get('observedObjects').forEach((el) => {
    el.removeObserver(key, this, this.observerMethod);
  });
  this.set('observedObjects', []);

  let observedObjects = [];
  this.get('myModel').forEach((el) => {
    el.addObserver(key, this, this.observerMethod);
    observedObjects.pushObject(el);
  });
  this.set('observedObjects', observedObjects);
}.observes('myModel'),
```

**Update 2:** If you want to support observing multiple properties (e.g. other models), you can do do that by modifying `observeMyModelChildren`:

```
observePropertyChildren: function (obj, attr) {
  console.log('setting up observers on', attr);

  var key = 'observedObjects.' + attr;
  var observedObjects = this.get(key) || [];
  observedObjects.forEach((el) => {
    el.removeObserver('@each.selectedValue', this, this.observerMethod);
  });

  this.get(attr).forEach((el) => {
    el.addObserver('@each.selectedValue', this, this.observerMethod);
    observedObjects.pushObject(el);
  });
  this.set(key, observedObjects);
}.observes('myModel', 'myOtherModel'),
```

Comment: Take a look at this [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a6d8c84f0b79fc5878a3cc308626d040)

Comment: Seems to be working...Just a couple of questions;
1. In above code, "observedObjects" just adds for the first outer array and tracks property within this arr[0]. I have multiple outer array elements

2. How can I modify the above to track for multiple properties ? i.e. In some cases, it would be "selectedValue" OR it can be "preSelectedValue" in other cases . What property it is would depend upon that object  itself. But I need to track change of either selectedValue/preSelectedValue

3. Also in observerMethod, can I get a context and check what the new selectedValue/preSelectedValue is?

Comment: Adding the above comments in orig question also for easy reading

Comment: The solution above works if there are multiple array elements within `myModel`. I've updated the solution for observing multiple properties (e.g. multiple models). When it comes to handling multiple leaf keys, you may be able to just add additional `add/removeObserver` calls for observing the other key. You may want to examine the element being observed in order to determine which key to observe so you don't create a lot of extra observers.

Comment: Not sure if I was able to explain the 1st part of the question well ("observedObjects" just adds for the first outer array)....
So here say this.get('myModel') is an array of 8 elements ...Each of these 8 elements in turn are arrays containing 4 objects...So with the above code,  in observedObjects, I can see only for the 4 objects belonging to the 1st outer array...i.e. I only get for this.get('myModel')[0]
and not for others

Comment: Also my other question was how do I get context of the inner object in observerMethod...Say I want to check for the "prop1" of the changed object.

Comment: Updated my solution to fix the bug you mentioned with observing `myModel`. Currently the context for `observerMethod` is the controller instance, which is set in the calls to `add/removeObserver` as the third parameter. `observerMethod` also receives two parameters: the observed object and key. It sounds like you want the observe object passed in to be the second-level array element and not the first-level array element. As written, you can't determine the second-level array, only the first-level array. You can expand on this idea of setting up your own observers in order to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is correct. I actually need to observe the root-level object attributes (i.e. those inside my second-level array)..
Can I take similar approach to custom implement it ?

Comment: Hey...I am unable to directly add observer to my object..i.e. I cannot do el[i].addObserver()...It says not a function...So I have no clue how I'll be able to add observer to the inner object...

Comment: Let's continue this discussion on the [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39726313/ember-addobserver-works-for-array-but-not-for-object) you created

Comment: would be great if you could add the update here, as unable to edit there